# loop.nextitem is always undefined in ansible jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I´m trying to loop over some list items using ansible in a jinja template. Looping works, but the special variable loop.nextitem is always empty. Any idea why?
What I´ve tried so far:

```
{% for quota in current_project.project_values.quotas | sort(attribute='date') %}
 {% if loop.nextitem is defined %}
  is: defined
 {% endif %}
 {% if loop.nextitem is undefined %}
  is: undefined
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Other special varaibles coming from jinja are well set. E.g:

```
quota-date: {{quota.date}} //accesses the items
index: {{loop.index}}   //gives me the index
last: {{loop.last}}    //false for all iterations except last one
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for ansible_loop.nextitem?

Comment: I found that also, but this is also undefined

Answer (score 1):

**ansible playbook:**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    current_project:
      project_values:
        quotas:
          date: 
            - y
            - t
            - z
  tasks:
     - name: template
       template:
         src: templates/test
         dest: rendered/output
```

**Below is working fine:**

```
{% for i in current_project.project_values.quotas.date | sort %}
{% if loop.nextitem is defined %}
    is: defined
{% else %}
    is: notdefined
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Output:**

```
t
    is: defined
y
    is: defined
z
    is: notdefined
```

Comment: I tried that already but this also didn´t work out. I´ll give it another try and let you know..